# Dividing Grid Into Parts using mvvm pattern in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I want to create the grid and divide the grid into parts using mvvm pattern in wpf.
    For Example
    If i have 1 record there should be only one part in grid.
    If i have 2 record there should be two parts in grid like 2 quadrants.
    If i have 3 record there should be 3 parts in grid like 4 quadrants and only 3 quadrant must have data.
    If i have 4 record there should be 4 parts in grid like 4 quadrants and all quadrants should filled up with data.
    If more than 4 record comes then i have to implement pagination following 4 quadrant pattern in all the pages.

Can anyone please help me on this how to create grid like this dynamically using mvvm pattern in wpf.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post some code that shows you've put effort into it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a Listbox. Set up the Listbox.ItemsPanel with a WrapPanel in it. In the DataTemplate you can have a grid to hold your whatever data you are looking to display. This will allow you to have as many "quadrants" as are necessary. It is also adapts ideally to MVVM.